# Entering India with a visa even though I previously overstayed as a visitor

Tags: visas, india, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a srilankan. In 2000 my family had to move to india due to the war in srilanka. In India I did my schooling and completed my degree, unaware that I was staying in India with a tourist visa (overstayed). I returned to srilanka in 2010.

Now I have a new passport and I would like to go to India for my marriage since most of my relatives are there. I got the visa also, will there be any issues in entering India?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a visa, chances are, you will be allowed to enter the country without a problem.

I haven't heard about any official refugee protection scheme in India. I am a Sri Lankan too and I stayed in Sri Lanka during the war era. It's unlikely that you will be able to negotiate the overstay to a refugee protection or something similar.

Having overstay records in the past is not necessasarily preventing you from entering that country. But the officers will be a little more careful when reviewing your immigrant paperwork.

Enjoy your wedding and I wish you both a very happy wedded life!